# Exponent calculation speed

Tags: algorithm, performance, julia

I am currently testing Julia (I've worked with Matlab)

In matlab the calculation speed of N^3 is slower than NxNxN. This doesn't happen with N^2 and NxN. They use a different algorithm to calculate higher-order exponents because they prefer accuracy rather than speed.

I think Julia do the same thing.

I wanted to ask if there is a way to force Julia to calculate the exponent of N using multiplication instead of the default algorithm, at least for cube exponents.

Some time ago a I did a few test on matlab of this.  I made a translation of that code to julia.

Links to code:
http://pastebin.com/bbeukhTc
(I cant upload all the links here :( )

**Results of the scripts on Matlab 2014:**

Exponente1

Elapsed time is 68.293793 seconds. (17.7x times of the smallest)

Exponente2

Elapsed time is 24.236218 seconds. (6.3x times of the smallests)

Exponente3

Elapsed time is 3.853348 seconds.

**Results of the scripts on Julia 0.46:**

Exponente1

18.423204 seconds (8.22 k allocations: 372.563 KB) (51.6x times of the smallest)

Exponente2

13.746904 seconds (9.02 k allocations: 407.332 KB) (38.5 times of the smallest)

Exponente3

0.356875 seconds (10.01 k allocations: 450.441 KB)

In my tests julia is faster than Matlab, but i am using a relative old version. I cant test other versions.

Answer (score 5):

Checking Julia's source code:

[julia/base/math.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/math.jl):

```
^(x::Float64, y::Integer) =
    box(Float64, powi_llvm(unbox(Float64,x), unbox(Int32,Int32(y))))
^(x::Float32, y::Integer) =
    box(Float32, powi_llvm(unbox(Float32,x), unbox(Int32,Int32(y))))
```

[julia/base/fastmath.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/fastmath.jl):

```
pow_fast{T<:FloatTypes}(x::T, y::Integer) = pow_fast(x, Int32(y))
pow_fast{T<:FloatTypes}(x::T, y::Int32) =
    box(T, Base.powi_llvm(unbox(T,x), unbox(Int32,y)))
```

We can see that Julia uses powi_llvm

Checking [llvm's source code](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/branches/release_38/test/CodeGen/XCore/float-intrinsics.ll):

```
define double @powi(double %F, i32 %power) {
; CHECK: powi:
; CHECK: bl __powidf2
        %result = call double @llvm.powi.f64(double %F, i32 %power)
    ret double %result
}
```

Now, the [__powidf2](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk/lib/builtins/powidf2.c) is the interesting function here:

```
COMPILER_RT_ABI double
__powidf2(double a, si_int b)
{
    const int recip = b < 0;
    double r = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        if (b & 1)
            r *= a;
        b /= 2;
        if (b == 0)
            break;
        a *= a;
    }
    return recip ? 1/r : r;
}
```

Example 1: given a = 2; b = 7:

```
 -              r          =   1
 - iteration 1: r = 1 *  2 =   2; b = (int)(7/2) = 3; a = 2 * 2 =  4
 - iteration 2: r = 2 *  4 =   8; b = (int)(3/2) = 1; a = 4 * 4 = 16
 - iteration 3: r = 8 * 16 = 128;
```

Example 2: given a = 2; b = 8:

```
 -              r           =   1
 - iteration 1: r           =   1; b = (int)(8/2) = 4; a =  2 *  2 =   4
 - iteration 2: r           =   1; b = (int)(4/2) = 2; a =  4 *  4 =  16
 - iteration 3: r           =   1; b = (int)(2/2) = 1; a = 16 * 16 = 256
 - iteration 4: r = 1 * 256 = 256; b = (int)(1/2) = 0;
```

Integer power is always implemented as a sequence multiplications. That's why N^3 is slower than N^2.

[jl_powi_llvm](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/runtime_intrinsics.c) (called in fastmath.jl. "jl_" is concatenated by macro expansion), on the other hand, casts the exponent to floating-point and calls pow(). C source code:

```
JL_DLLEXPORT jl_value_t *jl_powi_llvm(jl_value_t *a, jl_value_t *b)
{
    jl_value_t *ty = jl_typeof(a);
    if (!jl_is_bitstype(ty))
        jl_error("powi_llvm: a is not a bitstype");
    if (!jl_is_bitstype(jl_typeof(b)) || jl_datatype_size(jl_typeof(b)) != 4)
        jl_error("powi_llvm: b is not a 32-bit bitstype");
    jl_value_t *newv = newstruct((jl_datatype_t*)ty);
    void *pa = jl_data_ptr(a), *pr = jl_data_ptr(newv);
    int sz = jl_datatype_size(ty);
    switch (sz) {
    /* choose the right size c-type operation */
    case 4:
        *(float*)pr = powf(*(float*)pa, (float)jl_unbox_int32(b));
        break;
    case 8:
        *(double*)pr = pow(*(double*)pa, (double)jl_unbox_int32(b));
        break;
    default:
        jl_error("powi_llvm: runtime floating point intrinsics are not implemented for bit sizes other than 32 and 64");
    }
    return newv;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The info about math.jl and fastmath.jl is what i was looking for.

Comment: `@fastmath` actually calls `pow_fast` which is a generic function which, on the right types, calls the same `powi_llvm` as without the `@fastmath`. There is a bit of a type-inference confusion when the `@fastmath` macro is called from the REPL.

Comment: Also, `pow_fast` calls `jl_powi_llvm` - so can you add the `jl_` to the last link for powi_llvm. And thanks for the great answer which clarified some stuff for me (I'm working with 0.5).

Comment: @DanGetz: Thanks Dan

Answer (score 2):

Lior's answer is excellent. Here is a solution to the problem you posed: Yes, there is a way to force usage of multiplication, at cost of accuracy. It's the `@fastmath` macro:

```
julia> @benchmark 1.1 ^ 3
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     999
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
  memory estimate:  16.00 bytes
  allocs estimate:  1
  minimum time:     13.00 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      14.00 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        15.74 ns (6.14% GC)
  maximum time:     1.85 μs (98.16% GC)

julia> @benchmark @fastmath 1.1 ^ 3
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1000
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
  memory estimate:  0.00 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  minimum time:     2.00 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      3.00 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        2.59 ns (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     20.00 ns (0.00% GC)
```

Note that with `@fastmath`, performance is much better.

Comment: Thanks about the @fastmath macro. I will see how it perform on the data i need to analize and see if the cost of accuracy is not to high.

I dont know if i can close the post, but the reply's i got are enought

Comment: Note the first benchmark has an allocation. So they are not clearly comparable.